# Are my if statements messing up with my menu?

Tags: java, oop, if-statement

I created a fishing game with a menu. A user simply enters a letter to do that option. However when I try to access the code under the corresponding if statement, for some reason it either skips it or displays high score stats. I tried changing the letters to see if that was the issue that didn't work. Maybe it's the way I'm comparing the user input string (I'm using .equals) or maybe it's a bigger issue that I don't see. In short, my if statements aren't working as a menu and some if statements such as my r to 'ready up' for fishing doesn't do anything. Or my you to 'purchase upgrades' for the fishing rod.

```
//Intense Fishing Simulator 2019
//2019-10-29
//Ormim Bari
//to practice the usage of realtionships.
package com.mycompany.intensefishingsimulator2019_ormimbari;

 import java.io.*;

public class DriverClass 
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader MyInput=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        Fisher joe = new Fisher(); //creates the fisher

        System.out.println("Welcome to Intesne Fishing Simulator 2019");
        System.out.println("You join fisher Joe's in the intense world of Fishing");
        int money=0;
        int endGame=0;
        boolean purchase1=false;//if purchased firsst upgrade
        boolean purchase2=false;//if purchased last upgrade
        do
        {
            //menu
            System.out.println("Enter r when ready to catch a fish");
            System.out.println("Enter c to see total of cash earned");
            System.out.println("Enter f to see total amount of fish caught");
            System.out.println("Enter u to upgrade your fishing rod");
            System.out.println("Enter joe to see stats");
            System.out.println("Enter Exit to end game ");

            String strInput=MyInput.readLine(); //gathers ihnput

            //ends game
            if (strInput.equals("Exit"))
            {
                endGame=999;
            }
            //display hp and fishing rod damage
            if (strInput.equals("joe"))
            {
                strInput="";
                System.out.println("Joe has a total hp of " +joe.getHp());
                System.out.println("Joes fishingrod does a total of "+joe.fr.getDamage() +" damage");

            }
            //display career total of fish caught
            if (strInput.equals("f"));
            {
                strInput="";
                System.out.println("You caught a total of"+joe.GetCatches()+"fishes");

            }
            //display career total of cash earned
            if (strInput.equals("c"));
            {
                strInput="";
                System.out.println( "You earned a total of $"+joe.getCashTotal());

            }
            if (strInput.equals("u"))
            {

                if (purchase1==false)
                {
                    System.out.println("Welcome to the shop! The first upgrade is $30. To buy enter b");
                    strInput=MyInput.readLine();
                    if (strInput.equals("b"))
                    {
                        strInput="";
                       boolean sucess= joe.fr.Upgrade1(money, joe, joe.fr);
                       if (sucess==true)
                       {
                           purchase1=true;
                       }
                    }
                }
                if (purchase1==true)
                {
                    System.out.println("Welcome to the shop! The last upgrade is $50. To buy enter b");
                    strInput=MyInput.readLine();
                    if (strInput.equals("b"))
                    {
                        strInput="";
                       boolean sucess= joe.fr.Upgrade2(money, joe, joe.fr);
                       if (sucess==true)
                       {
                           purchase2=true;
                       }
                    }
                }
                if (purchase2==true)
                {
                    System.out.println("You purchased all the upgrades");
                }
            }
            //user chooses to 'ready up' to fish
            if (strInput.equals("r"))
            {
                strInput="";
                int endFishing=0;

                //creation of fish to fight
                Fish fish= new Fish();

                //ceratopm of all fish 
                TunaFish tf= new TunaFish(); 
                SilverCarp sc= new SilverCarp();    
                Shark shark= new Shark();

                //intro
                System.out.println("You have been approached by a " + fish.getType());
                do
                {
                    //instructions
                    System.out.println("Enter a to attack the fish or r to run away");
                    strInput=MyInput.readLine(); 
                    //if chosing to run away
                    if (strInput.equals("r"))
                    {
                        strInput="";
                        boolean sucess;
                        sucess=joe.RunAway();
                        //if sucesfull
                        if (sucess==true)
                        {
                            joe.RunAwaySucess(joe);
                            endFishing=999;
                        }
                        //if joe failed to runaway
                        if (sucess==false)
                        {
                            //if tuna
                            if (fish.getType().equals("Tuna Fish"))
                            {   

                                boolean damageGiven= tf.AttackChanceTuna();
                                //if tuna dosnt miss
                                if (damageGiven==true)
                                {
                                    //joe gets the damage 
                                    joe.HarmJoe(tf.returnTunaDamage());
                                    System.out.println("Joe has been harmed by the tuna for "+ tf.returnTunaDamage());
                                    System.out.println("Joe now has" + joe.getHp());

                                    //if joe dies
                                    if (joe.getHp()<=0)
                                    {
                                        joe.EndGame(joe);
                                        endGame=999; //ends game
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            //if carp
                            if (fish.getType().equals("Silver Carp"))
                            {
                                boolean damageGiven= sc.AttackChanceCarp();
                                //if carp dosnt miss
                                if (damageGiven==true)
                                {
                                    //harms joe
                                    joe.HarmJoe(sc.returnCarpDamage());
                                    System.out.println("Joe has been harmed by the silver carp for "+ sc.returnCarpDamage());
                                    System.out.println("Joe now has" + joe.getHp());
                                }
                                //if joe dies
                                    if (joe.getHp()<=0)
                                    {
                                        joe.EndGame(joe);
                                        endGame=999; //ends game
                                    }
                            }
                            //if shark
                            if (fish.getType().equals("Shark"))
                            {
                                boolean damageGiven= shark.AttackChanceShark();
                                //if shark dosnt miss
                                if (damageGiven==true)
                                {
                                    //harms joe
                                    joe.HarmJoe(shark.returnSharkDamage());
                                    System.out.println("Joe has been harmed by the silver carp for "+ shark.returnSharkDamage());
                                    System.out.println("Joe now has" + joe.getHp());


                                }
                                //if joe dies
                                    if (joe.getHp()<=0)
                                    {
                                        joe.EndGame(joe);
                                        endGame=999; //ends game
                                    }
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    //if attacking
                    if (strInput.equals("a"))
                    {
                        strInput="";
                        //tells user it did attack
                        fish.HarmFish(joe.fr.getDamage());
                        System.out.println("Joe has hurt " + fish.getType()+ "for "+ joe.fr.getDamage()+"damage");

                         //if tuna
                            if (fish.getType().equals("Tuna Fish"))
                            {
                                //damage the tuna
                                tf.harmTuna(joe.fr.getDamage());

                                boolean damageGiven= tf.AttackChanceTuna();
                                //if tuna attacks
                                if (damageGiven==true)
                                {
                                    //joe gets the damage if true
                                    joe.HarmJoe(tf.returnTunaDamage());
                                    System.out.println("Joe has been harmed by the tuna for "+ tf.returnTunaDamage());
                                    System.out.println("Joe now has" + joe.getHp());

                                    //if joe dies
                                    if (joe.getHp()<=0)
                                    {
                                        joe.EndGame(joe);
                                        endGame=999;
                                    }
                                    //if tuna dies
                                    if (tf.getTunaHp()<=0)
                                    {
                                        //reward screen output
                                        System.out.println("You beat the tuna!You got " + tf.fl.getLootType());
                                        System.out.println("You sold the " + tf.fl.getLootType()+ "for $" + tf.fl.getLootPrice());
                                        joe.increaseCash(tf.fl.getLootPrice());
                                        System.out.println("You now have $" + joe.getMoney()); //cash update
                                        tf.healTuna();//reset for next potential round
                                        joe.CareerCashTotal(tf.fl.getLootPrice()); //add to highscore
                                        joe.addCatches(); // add to high score
                                        endFishing=999; //stops the fishing
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            //if carp
                            if (fish.getType().equals("Silver Carp"))
                            {
                                //damages the tuna
                                sc.harmCarp(joe.fr.getDamage());
                                boolean damageGiven= sc.AttackChanceCarp();
                                //if tuna dosnt miss
                                if (damageGiven==true)
                                {
                                    //harms joe
                                    joe.HarmJoe(sc.returnCarpDamage());
                                    System.out.println("Joe has been harmed by the silver carp for "+ sc.returnCarpDamage());
                                    System.out.println("Joe now has" + joe.getHp());
                                }
                                //if joe dies
                                    if (joe.getHp()<=0)
                                    {
                                        joe.EndGame(joe);
                                        endGame=999;
                                    }
                                    if (sc.getCarpHp()<=0)
                                    {
                                         //reward screen output
                                        System.out.println("You beat the silver carp!You got " + sc.fl.getLootType());
                                        System.out.println("You sold the " + sc.fl.getLootType()+ "for $" + sc.fl.getLootPrice());
                                        joe.increaseCash(sc.fl.getLootPrice());
                                        System.out.println("You now have $" + joe.getMoney()); //upgrade cash
                                        sc.healCarp();//reset for next potential round
                                        joe.CareerCashTotal(sc.fl.getLootPrice()); //add to high score
                                        joe.addCatches(); //add to high score
                                        endFishing=999; //stops the fishing
                                    }
                            }
                            //if shark
                            if (fish.getType().equals("Shark"))
                            { 
                                //harms the shark
                                shark.harmShark(joe.fr.getDamage());
                                boolean damageGiven= shark.AttackChanceShark();
                                //if shark dosnt miss
                                if (damageGiven==true)
                                {
                                    //harms joe
                                    joe.HarmJoe(shark.returnSharkDamage());
                                    System.out.println("Joe has been harmed by the silver carp for "+ shark.returnSharkDamage());
                                    System.out.println("Joe now has" + joe.getHp());


                                }
                                //if joe dies
                                    if (joe.getHp()<=0)
                                    {
                                        joe.EndGame(joe);
                                        endGame=999;
                                    }
                                //if shark dies
                                if (shark.getSharkHp()<=0)
                                    {
                                        //reward screen output
                                        System.out.println("You beat the Shark!You got " + shark.fl.getLootType());
                                        System.out.println("You sold the " + shark.fl.getLootType()+ "for $" + shark.fl.getLootPrice());
                                        joe.increaseCash(shark.fl.getLootPrice());
                                        System.out.println("You now have $" + joe.getMoney()); //updatees cash
                                        shark.healShark();//reset for next potential round
                                        joe.CareerCashTotal(shark.fl.getLootPrice()); //adds to high score
                                        joe.addCatches(); //adds to high score
                                        endFishing=999;
                                    }
                            }

                        }

                } while (endFishing!=999);
            }



        }while (endGame!=999);

        System.out.println("Thanks for joining Joe in the world of Intense Fishing ");


    }



}
```

Comment: This is too much code with too little description of the error. Please narrow this down to a [mcve] and show example execution and what you're expecting it to print.

Comment: Try comparing it as a char? `strInput.equals('c')` . Why are you using BufferedReader and not Scanner?

Comment: I suggest you restructure your code and study the principles of object-oriented design.

Comment: You might want to step through your code with a debugger and check what's actually going on. Since the application is quite simple you should be able to run it in debug mode directly from your IDE. Learning to use the debugger is a helpful skill anyway so I highly recommend doing so - this will make it easier to spot simple errors without having to guess or ask others which might be even more time consuming (and you'd probably learn less).

Answer (score 1):

I think the size of the single `main` method is messing up with your understanding of the code behavior.

You give yourself hints as to what the code is expected to do by writing comments like: `//display career total of fish caught` and `//user chooses to 'ready up' to fish`. This is wrong.

All these hints should be refactored into methods. For example: `displayFishCaught()` and `isReadyUpFish()`.

This is a procedural programming; you may want to look into using classes and objects to move code out of the single class. You can find many object-oriented programming courses and tutorials.

After refactoring you would see that for example that when the user wants to exit the game all the unrelated code is still executed, guarded by a **sea** of `if` statements. This proves that your code is not maintainable without major headaches.

I am sorry as this is probably not the answer you were hopping to get.

Answer (score 0):

You have an

```
if (...);
{
```

So an empty statement when the condition is true (`;`) followed by an `{ ... }` block, always entered.

The variable `strInput` is too global, and is changed everywhere and could enter the wrong if-statement later on.

One solution use `else if`:

```
        String strInput=MyInput.readLine(); //gathers ihnput
        if (strInput.equals("Exit"))
        {
            //ends game
            endGame=999;
        } else if (strInput.equals("joe")) {
            //display hp and fishing rod damage
            strInput="";
            System.out.println("Joe has a total hp of " +joe.getHp());
            System.out.println("Joes fishingrod does a total of "+joe.fr.getDamage() +" damage");

        } else if (strInput.equals("f")) {
            //display career total of fish caught
            strInput="";
            System.out.println("You caught a total of"+joe.GetCatches()+"fishes");
        }
```

You can also remove the variable too:

```
        switch (MyInput.readLine()) { //gathers ihnput
        case "Exit":
            //ends game
            endGame=999;
            break;
        case "joe":
            //display hp and fishing rod damage
            System.out.println("Joe has a total hp of " +joe.getHp());
            System.out.println("Joes fishingrod does a total of "+joe.fr.getDamage() +" damage");
            break;
        case "f":
            //display career total of fish caught
            System.out.println("You caught a total of"+joe.GetCatches()+"fishes");
            breaK;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong input");
        }
```

A specific local variable is fine too.

```
        String menuAnswer = MyInput.readLine();
        switch (menuAnswer) {
        ...
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong input: " + menuAnswer);
        }
```

***Java conventions***
As opposed to other languages, polish notation `strInput` are not used in java.
Also variables by convention start with a small letter.
Variables are declared as near to the first usage as possible.
Class names start with a capital.